# Reading the value of a html a link

Tags: jquery

I have a link below and will like to read the value "Electric" and store it in a variable

```
        <a  title="This is cool" id="lnkTranslate">Electric</a>
```

I tried the code below but no luck. Any ideas please?

```
        var languageToConvertTo = $('#lnkTranslate').val($(this).html());
```

Comment: `$('#lnkTranslate').text()`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function like so..

`var languageToConvertTo = $('#lnkTranslate').text();`

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` is used to get the value of `input` tags.  `.text()` will give you the text between the opening and closing tags -

```
var languageToConvertTo = $('#lnkTranslate').text();
```